# ReactJS Bootstrap Alert if response is error in modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, bootstrap-4

I have a modal that contains a form. This form is trying to send and API call on submit. If the response is 200(there is an error) the backend even sends back the error message. As you can see I try to unhide the alert if the error message is 200 but it still closes the component on submit. How can I prevent this modal to close when I click the submit button, and only close on successfull submit?

Here is the form component:

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Form, Button, Row, Col, Alert} from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from "axios";

export default function OfferForm(props){
    const [StockList, setStockList] = useState([]);
    const [Stock, setStock] = useState("");
    const [Type, setType] = useState("CHOOSE TYPE");
    const [Price, setPrice] = useState(0);
    const [Quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
    const [CashAvailable, setCashAvailable] = useState(0);
    const [MoneyNeeded, setMoneyNeeded] = useState(0);
    const [Variant, setVariant] = useState("");
    const [AlertText, setAlertText] = useState("");


    useEffect(() => {
        setStockList(props.stockList)
        setStock(props.stockList[0])
        if (props.type !== ""){
            setType(props.type)
        }
        getStockDataForOffer();
    }, [Stock, props.symbol])



    function placeOffer() {
        axios
            .post(`http://localhost:8080/user/placeoffer/${Stock}/${Type}/${Quantity}/${Price}`)
            .then((resp) => {
                if(resp.status===200){
                    setAlertText(resp.data);
                    setVariant("danger");
                    alert(resp.data)
                }
            });
    }

    function getStockDataForOffer() {
        axios
            .get(`http://localhost:8080/user/getStockDataForOffer/${Stock}`)
            .then((resp) => {
                setQuantity(resp.data.stockQuantity);
                setCashAvailable(resp.data.availableCash);
            });
    }



    useEffect(() => {
        setMoneyNeeded(Price * Quantity);
    }, [Price, Quantity])

    return( 
        <Form onSubmit={placeOffer}>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <Form.Group>
                        <Form.Label>Select your stock</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control as="select" onSelect={e => {setStock(e.target.value)}} required value={Stock}>
                                {StockList.map( (stock) => {
                                    return (
                                            <option value={stock.symbol}>{Stock}</option>
                                        )
                                    }
                                    )
                                }
                            </Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <Form.Group controlId="type">
                        <Form.Label>Select action</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control as="select" onChange={e => setType(e.target.value)} value={Type} required>
                                <option value={"BUY"}>Buy</option>
                                <option value={"SELL"}>Sell</option>
                            </Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Col>
                
            </Row>
            <Row>
                
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <Form.Group controllId="price">
                            <Form.Label>Desired quantity</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="number" placeholder="Quantity" onChange={e => setQuantity(e.target.value)} required/>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <Form.Group controllId="price">
                            <Form.Label>Desired price in $</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="number" placeholder="Price" onChange={e => setPrice(e.target.value)} required/>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <Button type="submit" >Submit offer</Button>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    {Type==="BUY"? <h3>You have:{`$ ${CashAvailable}`}</h3> : <p></p>}
                    {Type==="SELL"? <h3>Number: {Quantity}</h3> : <p></p>}
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    {Type==="BUY"? <h3>You need: {`$ ${MoneyNeeded}`}</h3> : <p></p>}
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <Alert variant={Variant} show={AlertText? true : false}>
                        {AlertText}
                    </Alert>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            </Form>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the error messages working with a simple hook from the parent component